# Python reference count

Tags: python, refcounting

In the following Python code:

```
class Foo:
    def bar(self):
        return 1

def baz():
    return Foo()

print baz().bar()
```

#### Question 0:

When `bar()` is evaluated in `print baz().bar()`, what make the `Foo` instance returned by `baz()` to have not yet been garbage collected, since it seems there is no reference to it, like there would be in:

```
foo = baz()
print foo.bar()
```

where `foo` store a reference of the `Foo` instance.

#### Question 1:

If Foo and baz were implemented in C in a Python extension module, should `baz` increment the reference count of the returned object `foo` to set it to 1?

Comment: Part 0: there *is* a reference to the `Foo` instance: the parameter `self` in `Foo.bar`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answer 0: when `bar()` is called, bar is a *bound method* (bound to the `Foo` instance), which keeps a reference to its `self` argument, which is the `Foo` instance.

Answer (score 0):

For part 0:
Each time baz is called it creates a new object, Foo. You could see this by adding an **init** to Foo. So, before the print, the Foo instance does not exist. (It is not created when the function baz in declared, but only when it's called.

Part 1:
As with 0, declaring baz() does not create an object. Calling baz() does. The reference count is incremented when 'Foo()' (Constructor) is called every time function baz is called.